# Annoying 'Changes are not allowed...' message

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2010, web-applications

I hate dialog boxes, especially when they break my thought process *constantly* .

I debug my web application, and then go to change some things and it brings up this message. I have to press 'OK' and then 'STOP' and then I can edit my code.

Is there a way for VS to simply snap out of Debug mode, so I can code, instead of showing me an error message?

[image: Dialog box]

Comment: did you look in the Tools, Options, Debugging?

Comment: Toggling the 'Break all processes when one process breaks' didn't seem to change anything. Probably because the code is running (in debug mode) when I try to edit it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you go. Enable "Edit and Continue" under Tools, Options, Debugging.

More details at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7yty6a48.aspx

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if the keyboard shortcuts are the same in VS2010, but in VS2008, seeing that dialog requires only an [Enter] [Shift-F5] to allow editing.  This is much faster than mousing around.